# Using jQuery to restart an animation that is already hidden and transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a CSS animation which goes from Visible to hidden and solid to transparent at the same time. My problem is, this is an animation which I need to display when a button is clicked. How do I trigger the event on click, when the actual hiding and fading is performed by CSS and not jQuery? For example, when Div 'One' is clicked, I want the overlay to play once. Same when the other divs are clicked. I can't seem to work it out, and help would be great!

```js
$(".btn").click(function() { 
              
 var el     = $(".overlay"),  
     newone = el.clone(true);
           
 el.before(newone);
        
 $("." + el.attr("class") + ":last").remove();

});
```

```css
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
     display: table;
    background-color:rgb(39, 174, 96);
    z-index: 10;
}
h1.thank-you-message { font-size:12.0rem;display: table-cell; color:#fff; text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;-webkit-perspective: 1000;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}

.animated-thank-you { 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
    animation-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
} 

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutScale { 
    0% {visibility:visible; opacity: 1;transform: scale(1); /* CSS3 */
 -moz-transform:    scale(1); /* Firefox */
 -webkit-transform: scale(1); /* Webkit */
 -o-transform:      scale(1); /* Opera */
 -ms-transform:     scale(1); /* IE 9 */} 
    40% {opacity: 1;transform: transform:         scale(0.75); /* CSS3 */
 -moz-transform:    scale(0.75); /* Firefox */
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.75); /* Webkit */
 -o-transform:      scale(0.75); /* Opera */
 -ms-transform:     scale(0.75); /* IE 9 */} 
    60% {opacity: 1;transform: transform:         scale(0.75); /* CSS3 */
 -moz-transform:    scale(0.75); /* Firefox */
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.75); /* Webkit */
 -o-transform:      scale(0.75); /* Opera */
 -ms-transform:     scale(0.75); /* IE 9 */} 
    100% {visibility:hidden; opacity: 0;
 transform:  -moz-transform:    scale(0.5); /* Firefox */
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); /* Webkit */
 -o-transform:      scale(0.5); /* Opera */
 -ms-transform:     scale(0.5); /* IE 9 */} 
} 
@keyframes fadeOutScale { 
    0% {visibility:visible; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 
    40% {opacity: 1;transform: scale(0.75);} 
    60% {opacity: 1;transform: scale(0.75);} 
    100% {visibility:hidden;opacity: 0; transform: scale(0.5);} 
} 
.fadeOutScale { 
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutScale; 
    animation-name: fadeOutScale; 
}

.animated-fade-out { 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
    animation-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
} 

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut { 
    0% {visibility:visible; opacity: 1;} 
    40% {opacity: 1;} 
    60% {opacity: 1;} 
    100% {visibility:hidden;opacity: 0;} 
} 
@keyframes fadeOut { 
    0% {visibility:visible; opacity: 1;} 
    40% {opacity: 1;} 
    60% {opacity: 1;} 
    100% {visibility:hidden;opacity: 0;} 
} 
.fadeOut { 
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut; 
    animation-name: fadeOut; 
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay animated-fade-out fadeOut"><h1 class="thank-you-message animated-thank-you fadeOutScale">Thank You</h1></div>  
<div class="btn" style="height:20px;">ONE</div>
<div class="btn" style="height:20px;">two</div>
<div class="btn" style="height:20px;">three</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function runAnimation () {
  $('.overlay').removeClass('animated-fade-out fadeOut');
  $('.overlay h1').removeClass('fadeOutScale');  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.overlay').addClass('animated-fade-out fadeOut');
    $('.overlay h1').addClass('fadeOutScale');
  });
}
$(runAnimation);
$('#one').click(runAnimation);
```

```css
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
     display: table;
    background-color:rgb(39, 174, 96);
    z-index: 10;
}
h1.thank-you-message { font-size:12.0rem;display: table-cell; color:#fff; text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;-webkit-perspective: 1000;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}

.animated-thank-you { 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
    animation-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
} 

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutScale { 
    0% {visibility:visible; opacity: 1;transform: scale(1); /* CSS3 */
 -moz-transform:    scale(1); /* Firefox */
 -webkit-transform: scale(1); /* Webkit */
 -o-transform:      scale(1); /* Opera */
 -ms-transform:     scale(1); /* IE 9 */} 
    40% {opacity: 1;transform: transform:         scale(0.75); /* CSS3 */
 -moz-transform:    scale(0.75); /* Firefox */
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.75); /* Webkit */
 -o-transform:      scale(0.75); /* Opera */
 -ms-transform:     scale(0.75); /* IE 9 */} 
    60% {opacity: 1;transform: transform:         scale(0.75); /* CSS3 */
 -moz-transform:    scale(0.75); /* Firefox */
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.75); /* Webkit */
 -o-transform:      scale(0.75); /* Opera */
 -ms-transform:     scale(0.75); /* IE 9 */} 
    100% {visibility:hidden; opacity: 0;
 transform:  -moz-transform:    scale(0.5); /* Firefox */
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); /* Webkit */
 -o-transform:      scale(0.5); /* Opera */
 -ms-transform:     scale(0.5); /* IE 9 */} 
} 
@keyframes fadeOutScale { 
    0% {visibility:visible; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 
    40% {opacity: 1;transform: scale(0.75);} 
    60% {opacity: 1;transform: scale(0.75);} 
    100% {visibility:hidden;opacity: 0; transform: scale(0.5);} 
} 
.fadeOutScale { 
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutScale; 
    animation-name: fadeOutScale; 
}

.animated-fade-out { 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
    animation-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
} 

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut { 
    0% {visibility:visible; opacity: 1;} 
    40% {opacity: 1;} 
    60% {opacity: 1;} 
    100% {visibility:hidden;opacity: 0;} 
} 
@keyframes fadeOut { 
    0% {visibility:visible; opacity: 1;} 
    40% {opacity: 1;} 
    60% {opacity: 1;} 
    100% {visibility:hidden;opacity: 0;} 
} 
.fadeOut { 
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut; 
    animation-name: fadeOut; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay"><h1 class="thank-you-message animated-thank-you">Thank You</h1></div>  
<div id="one" style="height:20px;">ONE</div>
<div id="two" style="height:20px;">two</div>
<div id="three" style="height:20px;">three</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {

  var $elOvl = $('.overlay'),
      $elThx = $('.thank-you-message');
  
  function addAnimationClasses() {
    $elOvl.addClass('fadeOut');
    $elThx.addClass('fadeOutScale');
  }

  $elOvl.removeClass('fadeOut');
  $elThx.removeClass('fadeOutScale');
  
  /*
    We need to add classes AFTER they have been removed,
    so we postpone the adding of classes to the next frame with the next line.
  */
  
  setTimeout(addAnimationClasses, 0); 

});
```

```css
.btn {
  background: #3c9;
  margin: 9px 0;
  padding: 3px;
}
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  background-color: rgb(39, 174, 96);
  z-index: 10;
}
h1.thank-you-message {
  font-size: 12.0rem;
  display: table-cell;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.animated-thank-you {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutScale {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    /* CSS3 */
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    /* Webkit */
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    /* Opera */
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    /* IE 9 */
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: transform: scale(0.75);
    /* CSS3 */
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    /* Webkit */
    -o-transform: scale(0.75);
    /* Opera */
    -ms-transform: scale(0.75);
    /* IE 9 */
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: transform: scale(0.75);
    /* CSS3 */
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    /* Webkit */
    -o-transform: scale(0.75);
    /* Opera */
    -ms-transform: scale(0.75);
    /* IE 9 */
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    /* Webkit */
    -o-transform: scale(0.5);
    /* Opera */
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
    /* IE 9 */
  }
}
@keyframes fadeOutScale {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0.75);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0.75);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}
.fadeOutScale {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutScale;
  animation-name: fadeOutScale;
}
.animated-fade-out {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.fadeOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="overlay animated-fade-out fadeOut">
  <h1 class="thank-you-message animated-thank-you fadeOutScale">Thank You</h1>
</div>

<div class="btn">ONE</div>
<div class="btn">two</div>
<div class="btn">three</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start an animation on an element, you need to add a class to it. In your case `fadeOut` and `fadeOutScale`.

If you only want the animation to start on a click, you need to remove both your animation classes from your animated elements, so the animation doesn't start at load.

```html
<div class="overlay animated-fade-out">
  <h1 class="thank-you-message animated-thank-you">Thank You</h1>
</div>  
<div class="btn" style="height:20px;">ONE</div>
<div class="btn" style="height:20px;">two</div>
<div class="btn" style="height:20px;">three</div>
```

And to start the animation, you need to add classes to your animated elements and later remove them, so you can later add them again, to start the animation again.

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {  
    $(".overlay").addClass("fadeOut").one("animationend", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("fadeOut").find(".thank-you-message").removeClass("fadeOutScale");
    }).find(".thank-you-message").addClass("fadeOutScale");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to clone the overlay div for every click on btn div. Instead, just remove the classes applied for overlay div and h1 tag, and add the classes back after a small delay.

The script will look like:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    $("#overlay").removeClass("overlay animated-fade-out fadeOut").hide();
    $("#overlay h1").removeClass("thank-you-message animated-thank-you fadeOutScale");

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#overlay").css('display','').addClass("overlay animated-fade-out fadeOut");
        $("#overlay h1").addClass("thank-you-message animated-thank-you fadeOutScale");
        },1);
    });
```

See the code here:
[https://jsfiddle.net/code/](https://jsfiddle.net/ashinignatius/6concr51/3/)

Result here:
[https://jsfiddle.net/result/](https://jsfiddle.net/ashinignatius/6concr51/3/embedded/result/)